# Access Server via SSH When IP Address Is Blocked

Tags: ssh, centos, iptables, directadmin

The entire scenario of my situation seems 10/10 sketchy, I'll admit. So I won't bother convincing you this isn't a malicious attempt to access a server that isn't mine - I'll simply say once, that this is a legitimate need for assistance.

That said, basically my problem goes back to me being a little too restrictive when it came to SSH access to my CentOS 6 server. Basically I restricted access to my custom SSH port from only two IP addresses - one being my home address, and one being my work address - via iptables. The problem is, I no longer work where I do, and my home IP address changed ever since I upgraded my internet.

Obviously this means I no longer am able to connect to my server via SSH since I don't own that IP address anymore.

My question is, is there anything I can do to access this server? I have no console access, but I do at least know the IP address I used to use to log into the server (maybe possible to spoof an IP address, but I have no clue). The only other thing I can think of is I have DirectAdmin installed on the server and can still login with the admin account. Other than that, I've got nothing.

If anyone has any idea on what I can do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the SSH port number from Directadmin file editor (if you have root password),

Then restart the sshd service from service manager

And you can connect to SSH via new port number!